# How to convert (Rx1 and Ry1) to (Rx2 and Ry2)

Tags: elliptic-curves, secp256k1

I'm working with the secp256k1 elliptic curve and have point doubling and point addition formulas for this curve.

If a point is given $Q_x$ and $Q_y$

```
Qx = 112711660439710606056748659173929673102114977341539408544630613555209775888121
Qy = 25583027980570883691656905877401976406448868254816295069919888960541586679410
```

performing point doubling on the given points $Q_x$, $Q_y$ will get the below output

```
Rx1 = 115780575977492633039504758427830329241728645270042306223540962614150928364886
Ry1 = 78735063515800386211891312544505775871260717697865196436804966483607426560663
```

Performing point addition on the given points $Q_x$, $Q_y$ will get

```
Rx2 = 103388573995635080359749164254216598308788835304023601477803095234286494993683
Ry2 = 37057141145242123013015316630864329550140216928701153669873286428255828810018
```

Now, I'm looking for a way to convert $R_x1$, $R_y1$ to $R_x2$, $R_y2$ without knowing the original given values $Q_x$, $Q_y$. Is there a method or algorithm to achieve this conversion?

Comment: Ah, I finally understood what the question means: "Performing point addition on the given points `(Qx, Qy)`" should be read as  "Performing point addition on the given point $Q$ and the known generator $G$ of [secp256k1](https://www.secg.org/sec2-v2.pdf#subsubsection.2.4.1)". The stated `(Rx2, Ry2)` match that reading. So we have $R_1=2Q$ and $R_2=Q+G$. And it's wanted a way to compute the coordinates of $R_2$ from the coordinates of $R_1$.

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/148903/discussion-on-question-by-aviril-smith-how-to-convert-the-results-of-point-doubl); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Comment: Is anything wrong with the detailed answer given?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We are working in the elliptic curve group named [secp256k1](https://www.secg.org/sec2-v2.pdf#subsubsection.2.4.1) over prime field $\mathbb F_p$. The group law is noted $+$, known as point addition (point doubling in the special case of adding a point/element to itself). The group's unity (aka neutral, aka point at infinity) is noted $\mathcal O$. Other elements of the group are noted with capital letters $P$, $Q$, $R$, $G$ and have coordinates $x$ and $y$ in $\mathbb F_p$ with $y^2=x^3+7$ in $\mathbb F_p$, that is $y^2\equiv x^3+7\pmod p$, that is $x^3+7-y^2$ is a multiple of $p$.

The operations necessary to compute the group law $+$ are [there](https://www.secg.org/sec1-v2.pdf#subsubsection.2.2.1), including when we use point doubling or point addition, coverage for the specials cases of adding $\mathcal O$, and of a result that is $\mathcal O$. Formulas [formerly](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/revisions/108146/2) in the question did not cover that.

Scalar multiplication aka [point multiplication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_curve_point_multiplication#Point_multiplication): When $k\in\mathbb N$ and $P$ is an element of the group, we note $k\,P$ for the point $\underbrace{P+P\ldots+P}_{k\text{ terms }P}$ when $k>0$, and $0\,P=\mathcal O$. Usual algebra applies: $(j+k)\,P=(j\,P)+(k\,P)$ and $(j\,k)\,P=j\,(k\,P)$.

The group has known prime order $n$ (that is $n$ elements including $\mathcal O$, with $n$ a known prime). It follows that for any point $P$ in the group, $n\,P=\mathcal O$. That also allows to extend the definition of $k\,P$ to negative $k$.

---

The question boils down to: knowing that $R_1=2\,Q$ and $R_2=Q+G$, how do we compute the coordinates of $R_2$ from the coordinates of $R_1$ ?

---

We want to eliminate $Q$ from the two equations. We multiply $R_1=2\,Q$ by the integer $t=2^{-1}\bmod n$ (which is well-defined since $n$ is odd), to get $t\,R_1=t\,(2\,Q)$, thus $t\,R_1=(2t)\,Q$, thus $t\,R_1=(1+i\,n)\,Q$ for some integer $i$, thus $t\,R_1=Q+(i\,(n\,Q))$, thus $t\,R_1=Q+(i\,\mathcal O)$, thus $t\,R_1=Q+\mathcal O$, thus $t\,R_1=Q$. Substituting in $R_2=Q+G$, we get the desired $R_2=(t\,R_1)+G$, with $t\,=\,2^{-1}\bmod n\,=\,(n+1)/2$.

All there remains to do is implement point multiplication. There are methods to compute $t\,R_1$ much faster than with $t-1$ point additions (like with $\approx \log_2(t)$ point doublings and about half as many point additions), much like we can compute $12\times345$ faster than with $11$ additions of $345$ (we compute $x_2=345+345$; $x_4=x_2+x_2$; $x_8=x_4+x_4$; $x_{12}=x_8+x_4$ which is $12\times345$). This is a standard programming exercise, algorithm in the [aforementioned wiki on point multiplication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_curve_point_multiplication#Point_multiplication).

It's pretty simple. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##nZPLbptAFIb3PMVIUSrjYmXul0SpxNXLGLZVF8TGMbIDCI9l/PTpGdwmcauoUWeB4Fz@@c7PTHeym7ZhuutfXq7Qsm32tmzsHnVlb1G7RnZToVW1rpva1m3jIvtq2VEht8Tr0D3CQ/Z/Kx2fMc285jMyaRSGaRKnMsy4DjGLoiyhItVxgpnkhBNvDjITPCgTpVKqNDNJHEVhLESIJTUiTrXCEVaYmiiLk4iCGNWJESajmoiIyEwTZXSAB65ZmIRKURmymEshkpBn0IRTQrAOdZYQFXHAkFoIToyJuUqwzrKI4IRH2vc8sAyVq9UkD@b@LULoCnVt3VgXG40M0LEG4w8Wbcpmtaubp9HarlrW5Q4ty32196AN5UOQn2Cw/A7Nh2DuXudjYu@mzU@z@cmfdu1xkg8zKJiRoPOvu7GiGFzJfjqlszH5O95X9tA3kA4g6fqKwZ/lJ5cesVePu0k@Qr9hr9rDo4P8N/Yl9Rsqm@YDoJxh6TQ/fcwKVZ9EfT7sJttgceEwxGzd7eplefb5sHeUff20sTPbznbV2qLHuin70x@lZ/LxEAXYv0NbdH2PztF6DV8wMFp8Jz9uYaumAhuqHuHpAhoeUNP2aDt9cO9jg1vHTb2rIGPR9gu5fQ275ZqczYtxm2/f7hF5zTuCxd/hs9r2I52LsMOFLUcpdwgXQX5ZMIqT9xbnnlcQNzshQmkslDBKcUMlY5gZgbkSmlOl4YsayomiWnJBFcacMrhflAmOjaQSbqLAhmq4lFrLQGnFBJZMEKExZlpSQrQhjFDBuYB9QFcRKrEiShqlpSBGciY15kaCBIMMp1JILCXzvRwBo/vrk@Yr8W9uaFAQ/3xQjxV6qizMvO7bZ1QQr6C/xnd38P30V@OvXLbP3cFWqKBe18PBmRTUf3n5CQ)

```
# constants part of the definition of secp256k1
p = 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFEFFFFFC2F
n = 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFEBAAEDCE6AF48A03BBFD25E8CD0364141
G = (0x79BE667EF9DCBBAC55A06295CE870B07029BFCDB2DCE28D959F2815B16F81798,0x483ADA7726A3C4655DA4FBFC0E1108A8FD17B448A68554199C47D08FFB10D4B8)

def add(Q,G):   # point addition, without handling of special cases
    Qx,Qy = Q; Gx,Gy = G
    s = (Qy-Gy)*pow(Qx-Gx,-1,p)%p
    Rx = (s**2-Qx-Gx)%p
    return Rx,(s*(Qx-Rx)-Qy)%p

def dbl(Q):     # point doubling, without handling of special case
    Qx,Qy = Q
    s = (3*Qx**2)*pow(2*Qy,-1,p)%p
    Rx = (s**2-Qx*2)%p
    return Rx,(s*(Qx-Rx)-Qy)%p

def mul(k,P):   # point multiplication, using right-to-left binary multiplication
    Q = (0,0); k %= n
    if k and P[1]: # neither 0*P = O nor k*O = O
        while not k&1:
            P = dbl(P); k >>= 1
        Q = P; k >>= 1
        while k:
            P = dbl(P)
            if k&1: Q = add(P,Q)
            k >>=1
    return Q

R1 = (115780575977492633039504758427830329241728645270042306223540962614150928364886,78735063515800386211891312544505775871260717697865196436804966483607426560663)
Q  = mul((n+1)//2,R1)    # we get Q from R1
R2 = add(Q,G)            # and compute R2
print(R2)
```

---

If speed was important, there are so-called point halving equations that allow computing $(2^{-1}\bmod n)\,R_1$ considerably faster than by point multiplication. That's being discussed [here](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/108182/555).

Comment: Well, only almost: because the code for `add(Q,G)` is taken from the [original question](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/revisions/108146/2), it does not handle `Q` one of $G$, $-G$, or $\mathcal O$, that is `R1` one of $2G$, $-2G$, or $\mathcal O$. @AvirilSmith