# Validating slope (s) in secp256k1 elliptic curve

Tags: elliptic-curves

knowing the coordinates of $R$ on secp256k1 and an integer $s$, how do we validate that $s$ is the slope at the point $Q$ on secp256k1 such that $R=2Q$ ?

Answer (score 1):

> Knowing the coordinates of $R$ on [secp256k1](https://www.secg.org/sec2-v2.pdf#subsubsection.2.4.1) and an integer $s$, how do we validate that $s$ is the slope at the point $Q$ on secp256k1 such that $R=2Q$ ?

One way would be computing $Q=((n+1)/2)R$ by point multiplication as in [this answer](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/108154/555), then computing the slope at $Q$ and comparing to $s$.

But there's a better way. From point doubling equations we know that

$$\begin{align}s&=(3Q_x^{\,2})/(2Q_y)&\bmod p\label{fgr1}\tag{1}\\
R_x&=s^2-2Q_x&\bmod p\label{fgr2}\tag{2}\\
R_y&=s\,(Q_x-R_x)-Q_y&\bmod p\label{fgr3}\tag{3}\end{align}$$

I suggest this procedure, which starts from $s$, $R_x$, $R_y$ only.

1. check that $0<s$ and $s<p$
2. check that $R$ is on secp256k1, that is $(R_x^{\,3}+7-R_y^{\,2})\bmod p=0$
3. compute $Q_x=(((n+1)/2)(s^2-R_x))\bmod p$ (which follows from $\ref{fgr2}$)
4. compute $Q_y=(s\,(Q_x-R_x)-R_y)\bmod p$ (which follows from $\ref{fgr3}$)
5. check that $Q$ is on secp256k1, that is $(Q_x^{\,3}+7-Q_y^{\,2})\bmod p=0$
6. check that $(3Q_x^{\,2}-2s\,Q_y)\bmod p=0$ (which follows from $\ref{fgr1}$)

I'm not sure step 6 is necessary; it may be redundant with 5.

If we omit step 1, then adding $p$ to a valid slope can yield an $s$ that the other steps will accept, even though that $s$ could not be obtained as `s = (3 * Qx**2) * pow(Qy*2, -1, p) % p` as in the definition of slope given in the [original version of a related question](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/revisions/108146/2).

I made an example implementation in Python. [Try it Online!](https://tio.run/##nVRdb5s6GL7nV1iqNgEjmm38RbdMggC5XOB2miqakAaFAgKyhl/f89qkbbqj6UzHF4l5Px8/fl5303hoG191/fPzDdq2zTAWzTigruhH1O7ReCjRrtxXTTVWbaMtQ7ntKBdHYnVoifA5/X8rMb8rmlrN35RJojBM4lUiwpSpEPtRlMaUJ2oVY18wwoi1hjI2PssgSoSQSRrEqygKV5yHWNCArxIlcYQlpkGUruKIQjGq4oAHKVWER0SkishAefjMlB/GoZRUhP6KCc7jkKWQhBNCsApVGhMZMYAhFOeMBMGKyRirNI0IjlmkHMsCylCx29mZt3ZuEUI3qGurZtQ2Q6SHniog/jSiQ9Hs6qp5MNR25bYqarQthnKwIA1lZy@b4GDZF7Q@e2u9XRvHoE@bTYv15Lhd@2Rn5wUELIjXOR86E5GfdcjgunRhnC/2vhxPfQNuD5w6Lz87i2zSbgN7d1/bmQH9BnvXnu41yP@G/R71G1Tfzc4AZQZL3Wz6M1aI@kuoj6faPnqbdwyDbay6utoWM8@nQaPsq4fDuBjbRV3uR3RfNUU//RY6Izci8rDzBR3RhyWardUevuDAaPOD/LyFVk0JNJQ9wu4GEr6jpu3R0f2u9yZBr6dDVZfgGdHxI7l9NeulkzTNG9Pm27clIq9@jWDzb/Nc7finOu/MGi60NKW0CDde9j7AFCfXFGczodtDuT3eDXe/hrvcHrxcM3uDxrKuddEBPRYjhAzmVRjqtitRMUKb4bQ9gA32NFsu88uVernWQP7CIP46GA6Hr535t3MQhP9JLvLJNVe@XOK342VGEXb3iTifP4NsZnHkryo2MdOsmhdl5NO193IyO7u0yd7azP0vklxQd3CNqMBzzUla1KBny8qJbkMIlwpzyQMpWUCF72M/4JhJrhiVCr5oQBmRVAnGqcSYUR8eHupzhgNBBTxRHAdUwWullPCkkj7HwueEK4x9JSghKiA@oZwxDn2griRUYEmkCKQSnASC@UJhFggo4YOHUcEFFsJ3rAwBRj0OdjMz5uXEmSf4qUQPpb6lfd8@opxYOb3oQj9O17K4Mbxs28fuNJYop1bXw0TZOYUH7WWIf@Cf12MM8/A6yHP07xIijmM9P/8D)

Comment: The procedure you provided is one way it can be done but am looking for a approach that involves only $s$,$R_x$ and $R_y$. Can you give more insight on step one $0<s<p$

Comment: I added explanation on step 1. My procedure involves only $s$, $R_x$ and $R_y$ (notice that $Q_x$ and $Q_y$ are recalculated from that, and form $p$).